# Justify Navigation inside Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

As the Bootstrap example for justifying a navigation does not work for me, I tried to build up my own horizontally justified navigation. The code looks like that:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul id="navigation">
             <li class=""><a href="#">One</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Two</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Three</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Four</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Five</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Six</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Seven<</a></li>
             <li class="stretch"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The used CSS:

```
#navigation {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 21px;
    background: #ccc
}

#navigation li {
    display: inline
}

#navigation .stretch {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;

    /* if you need IE6/7 support */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}
```

When the navigation exist in the beginning, so like static code, everything looks fine. As my application creates the navigation dynamically, the links are inserted later. Then the justification does not work.

How to solve?

Comment: Can you please be more clear on your question. This code doesnt create the navigation dynamically. What do you mean when you say 'justification'? what is a menu 'justification'?

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Mohinder/PAvnp/

add this HTML and CSS with your Bootstrap CSS and check, I just have made it for you..

here is HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul id="navigation">
             <li class=""><a href="#">One</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Two</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Three</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Four</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Five</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Six</a></li>
             <li class=""><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is CSS

```
#navigation {float:none; text-align:center; display:table; list-style:none; width:100%; }
#navigation li { float:none; display:table-cell; }
#navigation li a { display:block; line-height:20px; margin:0px 5px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the justified navbar to work with collapse.

Html:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>


  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Css:

```
  .navbar-collapse {
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
 .nav-justified {
  background-color: #;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px solid #;
}
 .nav-justified > li > a {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #;
  font-weight: ;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0px  #;
  background-color: #; /* Old browsers */
  background-repeat: repeat-x; /* Repeat the gradient */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, # 0%, # 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#f5f5f5), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome 10+,Safari 5.1+ */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
}
 .nav-justified > .active > a,
 .nav-justified > .active > a:hover,
 .nav-justified > .active > a:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: none;;
}
 .nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
 .nav-justified > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .nav-justified {
  max-height: 52px;
}
 .nav-justified > li > a {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
}
 .nav-justified > li:first-child > a {
  border-left: 0;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
 .nav-justified > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-right: 0;
}
}
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
 .navbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
 .navbar {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're going for if you want to **utilize** Bootstrap's prebuilt classes.

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <table id="navigation" class="table">
                 <td class="text-center"><a href="#">One</a></td>
                 <td class="text-center"><a href="#">Big</a></td>
                 <td class="text-center"><a href="#">Jump</a></td>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> You must use "float:left" into the li

Comment: If you were to float the <li>'s, you would need to know how many there were so you could set a % width value to equally space them. But to truly justify them you need to use the <table> element's pre-applied "table", "table-row" and "table-cell" display: values, or apply those declarations to the children in that order.